# Having trouble updating an object's attributes?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I have a virtual method called Update Account, where based on the pointer found from a find method and returned to main, the account will update accordingly.

There is the parent class called Account, where Savings is derived from.

However, the savings will not output the updated interest and will not take the interest into effect.

All accounts have a balance and the deposit will not change among accounts, that's why I am calling the Account's deposit method

```
void Savings::UpdateAccount(Date *date)
{
     int   interestMonths;
     short lastYear;
     short lastMonth;
     float currBal;

     //THESE GET THE CURRENT DATE - Differs from the account creation
     //date and allows for the calculation of interest

     lastMonth = GetAccountMonth();
     lastYear  = GetAccountYear();
     currBal   =  GetAccountBal();

        if (((date -> GetYear ( ) - lastYear) * 12 +
           (date -> GetMonth ( ) - lastMonth )) > 0)
        {
            interestMonths = ((date -> GetYear ( ) - lastYear) * 12 +
                             (date -> GetMonth ( ) - lastMonth));

            for (int index = 0; index < interestMonths; index++)
            {
                currBal = currBal + (currBal * interestRate);
            }

           //This method takes the calculated current balance, then
           //passes it into the parent class method to update the 
           //private accountBal attribute. 

           SetBalance(currBal);
        }
}
```

The issue is that this method is not updating the balance for the object and I'm fairly certain my interest rate calculation is not the issue.

Thank you for the help - this method now works.

Comment: In general you can do so, yes. But the code you have posted doesn't seem to be the source of your problems, whatever these should be.

Comment: So what will happen if the account is not found? Hint the caller will get a pointer that it cannot possibly know if is right or wrong and try to dereference it.

Comment: @lovestogame227 You just heavily edited the question. Just a note: doing this will make all the past answers and comments seem irrelevant.

Comment: @Cinch Sorry about that, I'm sort of new here. Hopefully it isn't against the rules to do that. Otherwise I can delete the question and try again later.

Comment: @lovestogame227 As a person who's currently question-banned, deleting questions can also have downsides in the system. Just prepare your question better before you ask one before you end up like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating *a* balance, but on the wrong account.

```
void Savings::UpdateAccount(Date *date)const
{
     int   interestMonths;
     short lastYear;
     short lastMonth;
     float currBal;
     Account myAccount;
```

Here, `myAccount` is a local variable, unrelated to the account you just found (which is `this`) ...

```
 myAccount.SetBalance(currBal);
```

... and it's the balance of that account that you're updating.

You want to modify the object you're calling the function on, so just say

```
SetBalance(currBal);
```

and remove the `const` from the function — you can't have a function that updates an account but doesn't modify it.

You also don't need to add "Savings::" inside the definition of a `Savings` member —

```
 lastMonth = GetAccountMonth();
 lastYear = GetAccountYear();
 currBal = GetAccountBal();
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Tried this, but come up with this error:                                                       Multiple markers at this line
 - passing 'const Savings' as 'this' argument of 'void Account::SetBalance(float)' 
  discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void SetBalance(float) '                              EDIT: I'm didn't fully read your comment, just removed the const. Thank you for that.

Comment: @lovestogame227 Remove the `const` from the function.

Comment: @molbdnilo : You should update your answer. It would be bad to let it with a `const` method trying to modify the object ;-)

Comment: @molbdino Got it, this seemed to resolve the non-updating issue. Thank you

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's the original code with an explanation, it's not a correction.